# Error dimension mismatch MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've got a sudden error from my code. As I remember my code was working fine yesterday, and the problem is that I don't know which part of the code I've changed. (I don't think I've changed anything that could cause this error). Here is the code :

```
file_path = 'D:\Telkomiah\KULIAH\TUGAS AKHIR\Program\Uncontrolled and Controlled Dataset\';
per_all = [];
prompt = 'How many keypoints? ';
kp = input(prompt);

for idfile = 1:700
    if idfile < 10
           name_file = strcat('00',num2str(idfile),'.jpg');
    else
        if idfile < 100
           name_file = strcat('0',num2str(idfile),'.jpg');
    else
           name_file = strcat(num2str(idfile),'.jpg');
        end
    end


name_file
im1 = imread(strcat(file_path,name_file));
gray = rgb2gray(im1);
level = 1;

[desc] = Descriptor(gray,kp); 

   if idfile < 101
           imCat = 1;
   elseif idfile > 100 && idfile < 201
           imCat = 2;
   elseif idfile > 200 && idfile < 301
           imCat = 3;
   elseif idfile > 300 && idfile < 401
           imCat = 4;
   elseif idfile > 400 && idfile < 501
           imCat = 5;
   elseif idfile > 500 && idfile < 601
           imCat = 6;
   else
           imCat = 7;
   end


dataset1 = load(strcat('maindataset_',num2str(kp),'.mat'));

[a b] = size(dataset1.dataset(1,:));

CosDb = cell(1,b);

for j = 1:b
    datasets = dataset1.dataset{1,j};
    category = dataset1.dataset{2,j};

    Cosine = pdist2(desc, datasets, 'cosine');
    CosineSim = Cosine;
    CosIndex = zeros(kp,2);
    Count = 0;
    SumSimilar = 0;

    for i = 1:kp
        [k, ind] = min(Cosine(i,:));
            if k <= 1
                CosIndex(i,1) = k;
                SumSimilar = SumSimilar + k;
                Count = Count + 1;
            else
                CosIndex(i,1) = 1;
            end
        CosIndex(i,2) = ind;
        Cosine(:,ind) = ones(kp,1)*1000;
%         AvrSim = SumSimilar / Count;
    end
%     AverageSim{j,1} = AvrSim;
    TotalSim{1,j} = SumSimilar;
    TotalSim{2,j} = category;
    CountKey{1,j} = Count;
    CosDb{1,j} = CosIndex;

end

[~, indSim] = sort([TotalSim{1,:}],'ascend'); 
sortedSim = cell2mat(TotalSim(2,indSim));

per = size(find(sortedSim(:,1:100)==1),2);
per_all = [per_all;per];

end
```

and this is the error i've got :

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>
> Error in maintest (line 75)
>
> CosIndex(i,2) = ind;

EDIT :
i tried to delete `CosIndex(i,2) = ind;` and there is still a same error in the `Cosine(:,ind) = ones(kp,1)*1000;`

even though i've got this error, i still have the value of CosDb i dont understand why

I think I only changed the `imCat()` part and now I've got the error. I'm frustrated because this error comes out of nowhere 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: `@Mumir` Use debugger to debug through function and see what happens with the return values when you assign them to CosIndex(i,2). The chances are you that you have an `ind` value, larger than 1x1, being assigned to CosIndex. If this is what you actually want, you gotta define `CosIndex` as a cell. Cells can do the job better for you. Cells are not going to complain if you assigned variable size array element to them.

Comment: @hagubear can i put cell into cell? because i will put the `CosIndex` into cell `CosDb` (see code above). and this is very confused, my code is works really fine before, and i suddenly got this error :(

Comment: `dbstop if error` and then when it stops, check the size of `ind`.

Comment: @nkjt I've tried, its stop and the `ind` size is 1x0 (?) i dont understand lol, but if i delete `CosIndex(i,2) = ind; Cosine(:,ind) = ones(kp,1)*1000;` the size is 1x1. Im so confused

Comment: What is `kp`?  I see you take it through `input`.

Comment: @nkjt kp means keypoint, and i set it `50` keypoint

Comment: Since we can't see your workspace it's hard to see what the issue could be. `dbstop if error`, run it and check the sizes/values of everything, not what you think it should be but what it is when the error goes. Especially `i` and `kp`. Something must be an empty matrix if you're getting empty returns from `min`.

Comment: @nkjt even though i've got this error, i still have the value of `CosDb` i dont understand why (and the value is right). how can i get `CosDb` while i have an error in `CosIndex` this is so frustrating.

Comment: @Mumir          You didn't get it before and you are getting it now - it clearly means that you haven't considered your system bounderies properly - definitely not enough so that you can test it. Also, you could try and reshape your matrix to have a fixed size when putting it in `CosIndex` and then retrieve it somewhere else.